# I want to change the text of a UIButton but it says Expected expression in list of expressions

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

As the title states I have a problem with my code and don't know how to fix it. I will paste a picture of my code.

[image]

Comment: remove the "as" and in UIControlState placeholder  put a valid value like .normal

Comment: I have made the change but now it says extra arguement

Comment: I miss the = you need remove the = sing, in your next question in SO please post your code as code don't use image for your code

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting the text for the button, you added an "as" which should be deleted, along with an "=" after the call to setTitle which needs to removed. Your code should look like this:

```
let buy = UIButton()
buy.frame = CGRect(x: 100 + CGFloat(x) * (scrollView.frame.width),
                   y: 187.5,
                   width: 250,
                   height: 250)
buy.setTitle("Buy for \(50,000 + 50,000 * x)", for: .normal)
scrollView.addSubview(buy)
```